# Bernoulli Cusum Chart?

Tags: r, distributions, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, bernoulli-process

Can I use the R package named 'cusum' to make bernoulli cusum charts or should I use another package?

I've been asked to explore using Bernoulli cusum chart for trending a parameter that's usually 0 and then very infrequently has a positive value.

I'm a bit confused as to what a bernouli cusum chart is.

I read somewhere that a bernoulli cusum chart was just a binomial cusum chart with a n=1.

I looked at the R package 'cusum' and it seems to do cusum charts based on the binomial distribution? but when I try to set the n_patients (sample size) in the function cusum_limit_sim to 1 I get an error:

```
library(cusum)
data("cusum_example_data", package = "cusum")
head(cusum_example_data)
cusum_example_p1 <- cusum_example_data[cusum_example_data$year == 2016, ]
cusum_example_p2 <- cusum_example_data[cusum_example_data$year == 2017, ]
failure_probability <- mean(cusum_example_p1$y)
n_patients <- nrow(cusum_example_p1)
cusum_limit <- cusum_limit_sim(failure_probability,
                               1,
                               odds_multiplier = 2,
                               n_simulation = 1000,
                               alpha = 0.05,
                               seed = 2046)
cusum_cs <- cusum(
  failure_probability,
  patient_outcomes,
  limit = cusum_limit,
  odds_multiplier = 2,
  reset = FALSE)
plot(cusum_cs)
Error in quantile.default(unlist(rl), 1 - alpha) : 
  missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
```

I've searched publications and they do a great job of walking through a bernoulli cusum chat implementation without explaining properly what one is or how I would use one myself.

Thanks!